# How to write a ternary in PHP when you need an echo for only one condition?

Tags: php, echo, conditional-operator

I have some code

```
<?php (($f[2] != '') ? $f[2] : implodeList($l[3])); ?>
```

And the first condition: `$f[2]` requires an echo so the following works with that condition is met:

```
<?php echo (($f[2] != '') ? $f[2] : implodeList($l[3])); ?>
```

How the function for the second condition outputs an echo statement and can't change so only the first version of the code works if that condition is met.

I'm I stuck foregoing a ternary in this instance? I could rewrite with a standard IF. Secondary question, can you explain why they didn't make it possible to put the echo inside the ternary itself? Like:

```
<?php (($f[2] != '') ? echo $f[2] : implodeList($l[3])); ?>
```

In the past I've found that could've been useful.

Comment: Using a conditional operator for something that not really is an expression produces confusing code. What is the problem with `if` statements?

Comment: So, does `implodeList()` echo something _and_ return something? If it echos _instead_ of returning, it seems like the way you have it in the second code block would work okay.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use [`print`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.print.php) instead of [`echo`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php), because unlike `echo`, `print` behaves like a function which makes it valid to use in a ternary expression like this:

```
<?php $f[2] != '' ? print($f[2]) : implodeList($l[3]); ?>
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/ZCGQN)

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, simply inverting the logic can help, i.e., changing `!=` to `=`:

`$a != $b ? print('no match') : print('match')`
vs
`$a = $b ? print('match') : print('no match')`

Choosing one form over the other can also increase readability, especially if the "else" directive is somewhat lengthy.  Or, specific to your 3rd case:
       
`<?php (($f[2] != '') ? echo $f[2] : implodeList($l[3])); ?>`

moving your `echo` directive into the "else" position would have probably worked - without that extra set of parentheses - since `echo` typically looks at the `;` as the end of its argument, so the semicolon would have effectively been doing double-duty of both terminating the echo as well as ending the entire statement.

---

**However**, you issue here in your "working" second case was that the statement
`echo (($f[2] != '') ? foo() : bar())`
was doing an *unconditional* echo - echoing the result of the ternary expression.

Here, `foo()` is your `$f[2]` and `bar` is your `implodeList($l[3])`

```
<?php echo (($f[2] != '') ? $f[2] : implodeList($l[3])); ?>
```

- `$f[2]` evaluates to it's actual value, so `echo` uses that value as its argument
- But, `implodeList($l[3])` will either return the imploded list it created **or** it will return a value - `true`, `false`, or an integer.
  <sub>(I'd have to check the documentation on it's exact behavior -  my PHP is rusty)</sub> 
  So, whatever the value it returns ***is** the argument `echo` uses* and is what you will find printed as the output.